# Passing pointer to object in constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I want to create two objects A and B and each object contains each other.

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(B * b) : _b(b) {}
    void printB(void)
    {
        if (0 != _b)
        {
            std::cout << "B is not null" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "B is null" << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    B * _b;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A * a) : _a(a) {}
    void printA(void)
    {
        if (0 != _a)
        {
            std::cout << "A is not null" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "A is null" << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    A * _a;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A * a = 0;
    B * b = 0;

    a = new A(b);
    b = new B(a);

    a->printB();
    b->printA();

    delete a;
    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see object 'a' contains null pointer 'b'. What is the best way to re-write this code so that 'a' contains a reference to 'b'? (note that object 'a' and 'b' needs to use 'new')

Many thanks!

Comment: Two objects cannot contain one another, since every object is the subobject of a unique complete object.

Comment: you should use `setter` after object creation. Otherwise one has to be `null` because of circular reference.

Comment: References cannot be null. So you want instance of `A` to hold a reference to instance of `B`, which holds a reference to instance of `A`, which holds a reference to instance of `B`, which holds...

Comment: @chesschi, I am assuming that you mean *pointer* when you say *reference* because you have not yet learned about [C++ References](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/overview-refs.html) yet. If that is what you mean, it would be best if you edited your question appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a `setB()` method and call it after you are done constructing both.

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(B * b) : _b(b) {}
    void setB(B* b) {
        this->_b = b;
    }
    void printB(void)
    {
        if (0 != _b)
        {
            std::cout << "B is not null" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "B is null" << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    B * _b;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A * a) : _a(a) {}
    void printA(void)
    {
        if (0 != _a)
        {
            std::cout << "A is not null" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "A is null" << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    A * _a;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A * a = 0;
    B * b = 0;

    a = new A(b);
    b = new B(a);
    a->setB(b);

    a->printB();
    b->printA();

    delete a;
    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does it solve the problem `What is the best way to re-write this code so that 'a' contains a reference to 'b'` ? A still contains *a pointer* to B instead of a reference. Or maybe I got the question wrong.

Comment: @Spook, Given the phrasing of the OP's question and the structure of his current code, I deduce that he means *pointer* when he says *reference*, rather than a literal `&` reference.

Comment: Yeah, *reference* in C++ means something very specific. If it is the case, this seems to be a proper solution.

Comment: Sorry about that if it is not clear. Basically what I meant is when B changes, A will get B's latest change and vice versa. And the setter is the solution. Thanks!